# Why is ITaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition not working?

Tags: delphi, task, windows-task-scheduler, creation

I'm trying to programmatically create a task in Windows Task Scheduler using Delphi. Here's the code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ts: ITaskService;
  tf: ITaskFolder;
  tf2: ITaskFolder;
  td: ITaskDefinition;
  tr: ITrigger;
  tt: ITimeTrigger;
  at: IAction;
  ae: IExecAction;
  rt: IRegisteredTask;
begin
  CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);      
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler,nil,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_ITaskService,ts);
  ts.Connect(unassigned, unassigned, unassigned, unassigned);
  try
    tf := ts.GetFolder('\MyFolder');
    tf2 := tf;
  except
    tf := ts.GetFolder('\');
    tf2 := tf.CreateFolder('\MyFolder', unassigned);
  end;
  tf._Release;
  td := ts.NewTask(0);
  td.RegistrationInfo.Author := 'TheAuthor';
  tr := td.Triggers.Create(ttTime);
  tr.QueryInterface(IID_ITimeTrigger, tt);
  tr._Release;
  tt.Id := 'Trigger1';
  tt.StartBoundary := '2017-07-28T01:20:00';
  tt.EndBoundary := '2027-07-28T01:20:00';
  tt._Release;
  at := td.Actions.Create(taExec);
  at.QueryInterface(IID_IExecAction, ae);
  at._Release;
  ae.Path := 'C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe';
  ae.WorkingDirectory := 'C:\Windows\System32';
  ae.Arguments := '--help';
  ae._Release;
  rt := nil;
  rt := tf2.RegisterTaskDefinition('MyTestTask', td, 1, unassigned, unassigned, tlInteractiveToken, '');
  rt._Release;
  td._Release;
  tf2._Release;
  CoUninitialize;
end;
```

It works fine until `RegisterTaskDefinition` method. It returns nil and I think it's an error cause no task is created in my directory in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`. The directory `MyFolder` is creating properly.

But I can't even define error type cause there is no error codes returning in Delphi version of TaskScheduler api 2.0. It seems that all parameters of the function are correct but it continues to return nil instead of IRegisteredTask object.

Maybe I forgot something, or am doing something wrong?

I work on Windows 7 and Delphi XE 10.2. UAC is turned off.

Comment: `flags == TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY`, *Task Scheduler verifies the syntax of the XML that describes the task, but* ***does not register the task.*** Another victim of magical values :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I misunderstood which value must be in `flags` parameter. I thought there must be value from TTaskCreation set where validateonly is 0 and create is 1. But there must be value according to msdn - create is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the [**RegisterTaskDefinition**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381365(v=vs.85).aspx) method with **TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY** flag. That flag is described like:

> **TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY**
>
> Task Scheduler verifies the syntax of the XML that describes the task,
>   but **does not register the task**. This constant cannot be combined
>   with the TASK_CREATE, TASK_UPDATE, or TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE values.

So the call returns NULL pointer in the **ppTask** parameter because no task has been registered. If you weren't using magic constants and use proper defined constants like **TASK_CREATE** instead of 2 (or **TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY** instead of 1), you would find the problem pretty simply.

Comment: There is no **TASK_CREATE** or **TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY** constants in .pas api 2.0 library I use. Maybe I have wrong library, but it's good idea to add this set of constants to it for future using. In Delphi they cut HRESULT error codes(and S_OK) from Result of functions and moved there returned interface instances like IRegisteredTask which were var parameters. So I can't see whether nil result of function is error or not. And so the problem I had wasn't simple. But you're are right. My code works without _releases and CoInitializeEx/CoUninitialize.

Comment: I understand source of my problem. There is TTaskCreation type which looks like that `TTaskCreation  = (tcValidateOnly, tcCreate, tcUpdate = 4, tcCreateOrUpdate = 6, tcDisable = 8, tcDontAddPrincipalAce = $10, tcIgnoreRegistrationTriggers = $20);`. They are flags from msdn but this type has one error which makes Ord function return wrong result. I put number 1(this action is almost Ord) in fuction call after got error - incompatible types integer and TTaskCreation. All I must done to solve that problem with nil result is to correct TaskCreation `TTaskCreation  = (tcValidateOnly=1, tcCreate=2,`

Comment: Now I can use it in call of function `rt := tf2.RegisterTaskDefinition('MyTestTask', td, Ord(tcCreate), unassigned, unassigned, tlInteractiveToken, '');`

Comment: I see. Then your interface methods use `safecall` directive. Don't worry, if any of them fails (returned value will be different from `S_OK`), an exception will be raised. As for the rest, well, that's why I always translate the code from Windows SDK (not using any importer or 3rd party translation).

Comment: I need the same, but which pas library are you using in this code?